# Koala Gem get page insights

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I am using the Koala gem, and currently trying to get some of the Page insights like impressions etc..
I am presently using the below, which only seems to be returning `[]`

```
def page_impressions page_id
    @user_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.oauth_token)
    page_token = @user_graph.get_page_access_token(page_id)
    @page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page_token)
    @page_graph .get_connections(page_id, 'insights', metric: 'page_impressions_frequency_distribution', period: 'week')
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you request it like that?

```
@page_graph.get_connections(page_id, 'insights/page_impressions_frequency_distribution', period: 'week')
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. It still returns `[]`.

Comment: Hey @ACIDSTEALTH did you take a look at this page here? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights

Comment: I figured out my problem. I was mixing up the post id with the user id, which explains why it wasn't returning anything. Kind of embarrassing. for the answer though, I had the wrong code before finding this. I was trying to use `.get_object` instead.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH glad it helped! :)